# SQL Management Studio - Turn on line numbers

Tags: sql-server

Sometimes I have tables with lots of fields, and it would be very handy in my case to have line numbers, while in table design mode.

I have manually added numbers in red (left side)[image].

Is this possible in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I guess the answer is simply: no.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. For me, I rarely use table designer for official work. With line number, what would you like to do?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using Design Mode to edit your tables anyway.

Comment: I am making import from access to SQL, and I would like to have the line numbers for reference. But in any case, this is one time work. I will get away without the line numbers :)

Comment: yeah no line numbers. you could generate your create scripts in Excel, which would give you all the line numbers you want, and more!

Comment: @Jeremy that is excellent idea.